# Is there a linter for PHP that makes all exceptions explicit like Java?

Tags: php, exception

Is there a lint/static analyser for PHP that will warn when exceptions are not documented or caught? Consider the example:

```
// ERROR: InvalidArgumentException must be documented or caught inside method.
function divide($a, $b)
{
    if (0 == $b) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    return $a / $b;
}
```

To fix:

```
/**
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException if $b is zero.
 */
function divide($a, $b)
```

Since it must be documented, similar to Java's explicit `throws` on the method prototype. Then this should be possible:

```
// ERROR: InvalidArgumentException must be documented or caught inside method.
function calc()
{
    print divide(6, 2);
}
```

There are some obvious caveats with PHP, but in most cases these defects should be detected earlier. Is there any linters that do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

You'll need to add your own rules for PHPDOC, the [here's the Sniff](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/bac165a2d95c9bfb0bf3f76ffcf4aefeec24b817/CodeSniffer/Standards/Squiz/Docs/Commenting/FunctionCommentThrowTagStandard.xml)

I guess you add it to your rules with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My rules">
    <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag" />
</ruleset>
```

<del>But I haven't tested that.</del> Confirmed works... now I have phpdoc to add. :/

My phpcs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="PSR1/2">
    <description>Example</description>

    <file>./api</file>
    <exclude-pattern>*/Database/Proxies/*</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref="PSR1" />
    <rule ref="PSR2" />
    <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FunctionCommentThrowTag" />

</ruleset>
```

```
$ bin/phpcs

FILE: ...ttpdocs/api/Api/Version1/Software/AbstractSoftwareController.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 60 | ERROR | Missing @throws tag for "\DomainException" exception
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 5.55 secs; Memory: 19.5Mb
```

Comment: You can look for others using `bin/phpcs -e --standard=Squiz`. The `-e` means explain.